# .NET MEF создание нескольких экземпляров

Tags: c#, .net

В программе нужно использовать расширения. Хочу для этого использовать Managed Extensibility Framework. Поскольку расширения должны создаваться по требованию и расширение может потребоваться более одного раза, хочется получить список вида

```
[ImportMany]
SortedList<string, Type> extensions;
```

И создавать экземпляры самостоятельно.

---

Сейчас сделано так

Интерфейсы:

```
public interface IStatement {
  void Process();
}
public interface IStatementFactory {
  IEnumerable<string> Init();
  IStatement CreateInstance(string declarer);
}
```

Загрузка:

```
var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
catalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(this.GetType().Assembly));

//Create the CompositionContainer with the parts in the catalog
CompositionContainer _container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
try {
  _container.ComposeParts(this);
}
catch(CompositionException compositionException) {
  Console.WriteLine(compositionException.ToString());
}

//    [ImportMany(typeof(IStatementFactory))]
//    private IEnumerable<IStatementFactory> _factorys;
  _dict=new SortedDictionary<string, IStatementFactory>();
  foreach(var f in _factorys) {
    foreach(string key in f.Init()) {
      _dict[key]=f;
    }
  }
```

Но надеюсь есть решение получше.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, можно засунуть логику создания в плагин. Пусть возвращается фасад, спрячьте логику за ним.